# autoPanMargin in Openlayers is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, openlayers

I have an overlay in openlayers and I am providing the autoPanMargin of 100 pixels. It will work fine Chrome but in IE 11 if we click on the right side it will not work.

According to the [API,](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Overlay.html) autoPanMargin is the margin (in pixels) between the overlay and the borders of the map when autopanning.

So here is the overlay how I am using in the code

```
var overlay = new ol.Overlay(/** @type {olx.OverlayOptions} */ ({
    element: container,
    autoPan: true,
    autoPanMargin : 100
}));
```

Here is the [sample.](https://jsfiddle.net/3owL5cyd/) Check this in both chrome and IE by clicking on the right side of the screen. In Chrome it will pan. But in IE it will not. May I know the reason and possible solution for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking. This is a bug. I just created a [fix](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/6623), which will be included in the next release (> v4.0.1).

Comment: Thanks for you quick response.